# UITapGestureRecognizer not responding on animated subview

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a simple program that creates a subview and animates it across the screen.

As part of this program, I would like to add functionality when the subview is tapped.  I am using the following method to create the subview, add the UITapGestureRecognizer and then animate the subview:

```
int randomName = arc4random() % ([pieceNames count] - 1);
int animationDuration = arc4random() %  5 + 5 ;
NSString *randomPiece = [pieceNames objectAtIndex:randomName];

float yStart = arc4random() % 650;
float yEnd = arc4random() % 650;

UIView *piece = [[PieceView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, yStart, 75.0, 75.0)];
[piece setValue:randomPiece forKey:@"name"];

UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self
                                                                            action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
[piece addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

[[self view] addSubview:piece];

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^(void){
                     piece.center = CGPointMake(950.0, yEnd);
                 } completion:^(BOOL done){
                     [piece removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

Here is the code that handles the tap:

```
PieceView *pv = (PieceView *) recognizer.view;
NSLog(@"%@ was tapped", pv.name);
```

What happens is when a PieceView is touched the program does not respond.  However, if I remove the animation block then the program responds to the tap.

Why does the UITapGestureRecognizer fail to respond to PieceView when it is animated?

Comment: You are trying to tap the view before the animation is done, right? Because otherwise the view obviously won't respond since it's not in the view hierarchy anymore...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I struggled with this same problem, and it boils down to this: the animated view only ever **is** in two places: the starting position, and the ending position.  Core Animation simply renders the view's layer in interpolated positions between the start and end points over a period of time.

It's almost like when you look to the stars and realize that what you see is not actually what is happening *right now*. :)

Luckily, the solution is pretty simple.  You can put a tap recognizer on the superview and then inspect your animated view's `presentationLayer` (which **does** give you an accurate frame at any point in time) to determine if your tap is a hit or not.

I've built a simple `UIViewController` that demonstrates both the problem and solution:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MSMViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
#import "MSMViewController.h"

@interface MSMViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *animatedView;
@end

@implementation MSMViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect startFrame = CGRectMake(125, 0, 70, 70);
    CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(125, 400, 70, 70);

    // draw a box to show where the animated view begins
    UIView *startOutlineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:startFrame];
    startOutlineView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    startOutlineView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:startOutlineView];

    // draw a box to show where the animated view ends
    UIView *endOutlineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:endFrame];
    endOutlineView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    endOutlineView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:endOutlineView];

    self.animatedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:startFrame];
    self.animatedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.animatedView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{

        self.animatedView.frame = endFrame;

    } completion:nil];

    // this gesture recognizer will only work in the space where endOutlintView is
    UITapGestureRecognizer *boxTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(boxTap:)];
    [self.animatedView addGestureRecognizer:boxTap];

    // this one will work
    UITapGestureRecognizer *superviewTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(superviewTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:superviewTap];

}

- (void)boxTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    NSLog(@"tap. view is at %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.animatedView.frame.origin));
}

- (void)superviewTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    CGRect boxFrame = [self.animatedView.layer.presentationLayer frame];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(boxFrame, [tap locationInView:self.view])) {
        NSLog(@"we tapped the box!");
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution is much simpler, you just need to set the animation's option **UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction**.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.1, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
   ...
}, completion: { (completed) in
   ...
}
```